# crossbrowser unresizable textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm having some hard time with finding a solution for making text areas not-resizable, i have read about options for Chrome and Safari {resizable:none;} but not a cross browser one.
alsom the attributes maxwidth and maxheigth aren't working.

Do you have some tips?

Comment: I find that textarea elements stay at the size I set rather than being resizable. Maybe if you show (the relevant part of) your HTML?

Comment: They built those features so evil web developers couldn't limit the size of the textarea and we could size them appropriately so we could see what we were typing. No matter what, the user's selected size should always override what the website has set.

Comment: @nnnnnn hi, i'm simply using <textarea name="target" rows="5" cols="5" style="resize:none;"></textarea>

Comment: What browsers other than the webkit ones allow the user to resize textareas?

Comment: Firefox and Safari on mac for example,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resize` is a [standard](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) CSS3 attribute. Setting it to `none` should prevent resizing on all CSS3 compliant browsers such as Firefox, Safari and Chrome. You can also specify it to `horizontal` or `vertical` to only lock one of the dimensions. IE9 [does not support resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx).